# configure the Prettier extension to use the locally installed Prettier?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, npm-package, prettier-vscode

When I press `ctrl+s`, the file gets formatted by the Prettier extension in VS Code. However, it seems to be slower when compared to the locally installed Prettier using `npm install -g prettier`. Please correct me if I am wrong. How can I configure the Prettier extension to use the locally installed Prettier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `prettier.prettierPath` setting. Its description: "*Path to the prettier module*". You may need to use the `${userHome}` variable or other [VS Code variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) in the value depending on where your Prettier is.

I don't know if your own installed one will be faster than the Prettier one. The slowdown you're observing may just be part of the Prettier extension and not Prettier.